# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int' for degrees

Tags: python, string, int, typeerror

I can't figure out why this doesn't work, I'm still new to python. can someone help me please? This is the code that is causing the error in the title:

```
temp=input("Enter Your Temp for Fahrenheit: ")    
print ("The temperature in Celsius is: ") 
print (str(int((temp-32)*5/9))+"°C")

temper=input("Enter Your Temp for Celsius: ") 
print ("The temperature in Fahrenheit is:")
print ((str(int((temper)*1.8)+32))+"°F")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `temp` is a string and you are trying to perform `temp - 32` which won't work. Cast your `temp` to `int` first:

```
temp = int(input("Enter Your Temp for Fahrenheit: "))
```

Now this will work:

```
>>> temp = 33
>>> print (str((temp-32)*5/9)+"°C")
0.5555555555555556°C
```

Same goes for the second input:

```
>>> temper = 5
>>> print (str(temper*1.8+32)+"°F")
41.0°F
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Idos